# save the effort in/to/into

Tags: prepositions

> In an increasingly mobile society, people only stay in one place for a relatively short period of time. As a result, they often save the effort **in/to/into** building meaningful relationship with neighbours.

Which one is correct?

Comment: By saving the effort, do you mean *not* building meaningful relationships?  The wording is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In an increasingly mobile society, people only stay in one place for a relatively short period of time. As a result, they often save the effort IN building meaningful relationship with neighbours.

TO requires a finite verb. **Building** is a gerund, which is not a finite verb.

INTO. You can put 'effort into building something', but you can't 'save effort into building something'.

This leaves 'IN' which works well with this sentence.

You cannot say 'building meaningful relationship with neighbors'. 'Relationship' is a countable noun, so you need to say either:

> building a meaningful relationship with neighbours

or

> building meaningful relationships with neighbours

For example, your sentence could be written as :

> In an increasingly mobile society, people only stay in one place for a relatively short period of time. As a result, they often save the effort IN building meaningful relationships with neighbours.